# Switching views upon rotation not working properly

Tags: ios, ipad, rotation

I've been trying several approaches to get the rotation working as expected but so far I've been facing some problems.

Now I would like to have one class with one xib file containing the 2 orientation views. One for portrait, one for landscape.

I am trying this in my main ViewController (the root controller set in the app delegate. But somehow it's failing : when I rotate, the view is switched but the outlets are not rotated. For instance a simple label from the landscape view will be shown as if the device was in portrait mode.

Here's bits of code :

In my app delegate

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    //self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil withOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

In Viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}


 - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
   }



  - (void)updateLandscapeView2
  {
      UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
      if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
    {
    self.view = self.landscapeView;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"landscape" object:nil];
    }
else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
{
    self.view = self.portraitView;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"portrait" object:nil];
    }
  }
```

I intend to forward the orientation change to the subviews of Viewcontroller by using local notifications.

Anyway, what am I missing here ? I don't understand why this is failing.

Answer (score 0):

What i have found is that when you call

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation
```

inside the context of a

```
[viewController performSelector .....]
```

It didn't work.

Some body with a solution for these?